# How can I generate a dynamic file name for my PDF File with dompdf?

Tags: php, filenames, dompdf

I am using dompdf which seems to be going really well.

I get my generated pdf file as an email attachment. I wanted to know how to append a unique number to the file name so that every users that receives the pdf does not have the same exact file name.

I currently get name the file and get whatever I name have assigned it successfully, such as myfile.pdf.

As a test, I can also get a random number appended to the filename like this:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                       ->setSubject('My Subject Text') // Message subject
                       ->setTo(array('me@mydomain.com' => 'MyName'))   // Array of people to send to
                       ->setFrom(array('no-reply@mydomain.com' => 'SenderName')) // From:
                       ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html') // Attach that HTML message from earlier
                       ->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, 'myfile'.rand(10,1000).'.pdf', 'application/pdf')); // Attach the generated PDF from earlier
```

That works great for sending a pdf with the filename and random number.

But how can I do this with something that makes more sense?

Like starting with a specific number and auto-incrementing for every file that gets submitted?

Or using numbers based on (or from) the SESSION?

What is the best practice that would make sense?

I would like each file name to be myfile_UNIQUENUMBER.pdf (I think some type of auto-increment or SESSION number would be best)

Thoughts?

Comment: PHP has a nice [`uniqid()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) for this sort of thing

Comment: what is in the pdf? I only ask because a date/time works really well for this sort of thing. Can be the date/time of the data in the pdf in the case of a report or the date/time the pdf was created/run.

Comment: yes, I think date and time might work. Is there anyway to format the date and time? or does its just write as a string of numbers like : 101420111042 // meaning is that 10/14/2011 10:42?

Comment: http://www.php.net/date any valid filename characters will work. `$name='myfile_'.date('m-d-Y_hia)';`

Comment: @Johntahan Kuhn

> php.net/date any valid filename characters will work.
> $name='myfile_'.date('m-d-Y_hia)'; – Jonathan Kuhn 21 mins ago

I am not sure if your text ('m-d-Y_hia)' was a typo with the single quote outside the parenthesis, but your direction was extremely helpful.

This worked perfectly :

    ->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, 'myfile_'.date ('m-d-Y_hia').'.pdf', 'application/pdf')); // Attach the generated PDF from earlier

SENDS ME:

myfile_10-14-2011_0238pm.pdf


How do I give you credit for the help if your help only shows as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the date as unique number when use it with `d/m/year` AND TIME with a name you choose so every filename will have different number..try this code :

```
  $tym = date('m-d-Y : hi a');
  $filename = ' APPLICATION '.$tym; // YOU CAN CHOOSE YOUR FILE NAME
  $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content,  $_POST["username"] . $filename. ".pdf", 'application/pdf')); //
```